# Not able to import a node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I would like to implement a project in JS, HTML and CSS. For this I need a datepicker. I have decided to use vanillajs-datepicker.

My **webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './resource/js/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
};
```

In my app.js I make the `import Datepicker from './../../node_modules/vanillajs-datepicker/js/Datepicker';`

In the browser console I get the following error message:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/node_modules/vanillajs-datepicker/js/Datepicker
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2ms]

Loading failed for the module with source "http://localhost:8080/node_modules/vanillajs-datepicker/js/Datepicker". localhost:8080:31:1
Loading module from "http://localhost:8080/node_modules/vanillajs-datepicker/js/Datepicker" was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type ("text/html").
```

### update

**my app.js**

```
import Datepicker from './../../node_modules/vanillajs-datepicker/js/Datepicker';

const elem = document.querySelector('input[name="dp"]');
const datepicker = new Datepicker(elem, {
    autohide: true,
    buttonClass: "text-gray-500",
    title: 'db'
});
```

**my index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanillajs-datepicker@1.1.4/dist/css/datepicker.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>title</h1>
    <input type="text" name="dp" class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-500 w-full">

    <script src="js/app.js" lang="text/javascript" type="module"></script>
    <script src="bundle.js" lang="text/javascript" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

What went wrong?

### Update - Solution

As is so often the case, the error is in front of the keyboard.

The problem was. I discreetly referenced the uncompiled source code in my HTML.

```
    <script src="js/app.js" lang="text/javascript" type="module"></script>
    <script src="bundle.js" lang="text/javascript" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

If i deleted the reference to app.js then it works. Thanks for the comments and answears.
And thanks to **@esqew!**

Comment: Did you actually run `webpack`…? You should be referencing `bundle.js` in your HTML; however we can’t give you much concrete advice since you haven’t provided said HTML here. Can you show us what isn’t working with code that conforms to [mre]?

Comment: @esqew You are right. I updated the question with html and with the app.js file. i am new to webpack and it confuses me a lot....

Comment: If you’re using `webpack` to compile `app.js` and its dependencies into a single `bundle.js`, why have you still referenced the uncompiled source discretely in your HTML? Can you provide a link to the source document upon which you’re basing your implicit claim that this is the correct way to reference your JS source code…? Have you read [`webpack`’s Getting Started document](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/), which makes explicit mention that “*since we'll be bundling our scripts, we have to update our `index.html` file […] to load the bundle, instead of the raw `./src` file*”.

Comment: @esqew You are right! that is the mistake! Thank you, I will change it. And thanks for the link to the "Getting started with webpack" document. Top!

Comment: @esqew can you leave a short answer so that i can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re using `webpack` to compile `app.js` and its dependencies into a single `bundle.js` (as your configuration file would indicate), you should no longer be referencing any of the uncompiled source in your HTML. The whole point of using a tool like `webpack` is to distill your code and its dependencies into a single minified output file (except of course in the case when you’ve configured it otherwise).

You should revisit [`webpack`’s Getting Started document](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/), which makes explicit mention of this:

> […] since we'll be bundling our scripts, we have to update our `index.html` file […] to load the bundle, instead of the raw `./src` file….

Answer (score -2):

Looks like your import statement has a typo:

```
import Datepicker from './../../node_modules/vanillajs-datepicker/js/Datepicker';
```

'./' is used for a file in the same directory. If you're going back 3 directories use     `import Datepicker from '../../../node_modules/vanillajs-datepicker/js/Datepicker';`

Comment: Thank you! You mean: `../../node_mod..`  Both are possible. however, this does not solve the problem. i have supplemented my question with the html and the app.js.